# Vue2 window addEventListener scroll doesnt fire?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component, and I simply cannot get

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   console.log('scrolling');
});
```

to fire - I've tried to attach it to the `created` and `mounted` lifecycle hooks, however, it doesn't print to the console when scrolling.

At the moment I have the following, but still no luck. It fires the `console.log("My Method")` but not the scroll :(

```
 export default {
  data() {
      return {

      }
  },
  components: {

  },
  methods: {
    myMethod(){
      console.log("my method");
      window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        console.log('scrolling');
      });
    }
  },
  created() {
     console.log("created");

  },
  mounted(){
    console.log("mounted");
    this.myMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/nts6uk3y/ Do you want the "wheel" event instead? https://jsfiddle.net/jt9rbjyn/

Comment: Im using it inside a component - Could that have anything to do with it not working at my end?

Comment: No its all the same html. Is the window actually scrolling though? You're not just moving the mouse wheel over an element?

Comment: Funny thing... If I change it to a "resize" event in my app, then it fires, but not the scroll :( Seems like a plugin might disable thw whole scroll event or something... :/

Comment: Is it the `window` that's scrolling or are you scrolling an element that has `overflow: scroll` style? The [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event doesn't bubble.

Comment: Ahhh, thats the problem :/ Didn't know that :/

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thanks a bunch man I had the same issue. In my case I had the overflow property of body and html set to auto. 1 question though. Isn't that supposed to be a proper way of handling overflow behavior aka "resetting css" ?

Comment: Same problem here, i still can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  console.log("scroll");
}, true);
```

?